# How to execute a stored procedure which has its object name stored in a variable

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, ssis

I have a table which contains a column of stored procedures associated with each tuple. I have an `Execute SQL Task` which selects the procedure for the desired tuple and stores it in a variable. I then connect that to another `Execute SQL Task` which uses the statement `EXEC ?` and map the variable as a parameter. It fails to execute though, showing an error:

> The type for parameter '@P1' cannot be deduced in this context

This is how the variable looks:

```
@[User::ProcedureName] = "dbo.TestProcedure"
```

The `Execute SQL Task` for getting procedure name

```
SELECT ProcedureName FROM Table WHERE ProcedureID = 1
```

Results into @[User::ProcedureName]

The `Execute SQL Task` for executing procedure

```
EXEC ?
```

With @[User::ProcedureName] as a parameter

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add "EXEC " into the value of `@ProcedureName`, so that the value becomes "EXEC dbo.TestProcedure" and in your Execute SQL Task, select the "Variable" option for SQLSourceType and use the `@ProcedureName` variable as the source.

Comment: Duh! Thanks. I need to add a CASE statement because not all entries are procedures, we have a column for identifying types

Answer (score 2):

`Exec` does support a procedure name in a variable. If you omit the parentheses this is how it is interpreted.

If you change your SQL to

```
DECLARE @Proc NVARCHAR(250) = ?

EXEC @Proc
```

It should work fine and be SQL injection free.